# EtherApe not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gtk, etherape

I tried executing etherape through the terminal and this was the output, how do I fix it

```
 (etherape:19453): libglade-WARNING **: 22:36:39.057: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 (etherape:19453): libglade-WARNING **: 22:36:39.131: unknown widget class 'GnomeCanvas'
 (etherape:19453): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:36:39.131: gtk_scrolled_window_add(): cannot add non scrollable widget use gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport() instead
 EtherApe-INFO: 22:36:39.141: sctp protocol not supported
 EtherApe-INFO: 22:36:39.141: ddp protocol not supported
 EtherApe-INFO: 22:36:39.141: ddp protocol not supported
 EtherApe-INFO: 22:36:39.141: ddp protocol not supported
 EtherApe-INFO: 22:36:39.141: ddp protocol not supported
 (etherape:19453): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 22:36:39.142: invalid cast from 'GtkLabel' to 'GnomeCanvas'
 (etherape:19453): GnomeCanvas-CRITICAL **: 22:36:39.142: gnome_canvas_root: assertion 'GNOME_IS_CANVAS (canvas)' failed
 (etherape:19453): GnomeCanvas-CRITICAL **: 22:36:39.142: gnome_canvas_item_new: assertion 'GNOME_IS_CANVAS_GROUP (parent)' failed
 ERROR:diagram.c:250:addref_canvas_obj: assertion failed: (obj) unexpected EOF in read_all() critical: read_all() failed on control socket
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It came by default, but I did uninstall and reinstalled and I never was able to run it

Answer (score 3):

This is a dependency issue for `etherape`. Please install `libgnomeui` to fix it:

`sudo apt install libgnomeui-0`

Comment: Had the same problem and the fix works. Thanks @LoBS.